# A data compromise

Tags: word-usage, technical

I know that security people use the verb "to compromise" with the meaning of "to break", for example in "the integrity of the account has been compromised". But is it okay to also use the noun "compromise" in this context? My dictionary only has that meaning as a verb ("to weaken"), but the noun seems to be reserved for "middle state between conflicting opinions". On the other hand, you get a lot of hits on Google for "data compromise".

Comment: Real life example from Visa Asia: "In case of compromise": http://www.visa-asia.com/ap/au/merchants/riskmgmt/aisnew_compromise.shtml

Comment: That's the title, but in the body text "compromise" is expanded to "account compromise".  "This section helps you to understand what you should do to prepare for and what action to take, should your organization suffer an **information security breach.**  Incident response procedure for **account compromise**"  (Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use **compromise** as a noun in a security context.  Some possible alternatives:

- **breach**
- **penetration**
- **exploit**

These all have other meanings, but each of them has gained traction in a security setting and would be understood (although "penetration" might cause some giggles among the middle-school crowd) in a way that "compromise" would not.

Comment: Agree-- it's not that common I don't think to use "compromise" as a noun, though I suppose I'd understand it if I saw it used like that.

Comment: The way I would put it is that the other meanings of "compromise" as a noun collide with the intended meaning in ways that the other meanings of my alternate words do not; the domains are different.  It's not that "compromise" is not appropriate here, just that it's not clear.

Answer (score 3):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compromise?o=1000740) gives

> **-verb**
> 6) to expose or make vulnerable to danger, suspicion, scandal, etc.; jeopardize: *a military oversight that compromised the nation's defenses.*
>
> **-noun**
> 4) an endangering, especially of reputation; exposure to danger, suspicion, etc.: *a compromise of one's integrity.*

So, from the above example, "a **compromise** of one's integrity." does not refer to settlement or related, but to endangering and exposure and should correspond to the security related meaning of the verb "to compromise".

Comment: @Unreason - "One's integrity" refers to personal integrity/honesty; "a compromise of one's integrity" would be a moral failing which threatened one's reputation (see the beginning of the definition).  I would avoid using "compromise" as a noun at all in this context - it's too loaded with other meanings.

Comment: @MT_Head, I believe you are twisting the definition, let me rephrase it properly according to punctuation: an endangering*, exposure to danger** (*-especially of reputation, **-to danger, suspicion, etc). Also look at Thilo's link http://www.visa-asia.com/ap/au/merchants/riskmgmt/aisnew_compromise.shtml

Comment: also, searching for "security compromise" yields results in books http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=security+compromise&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=2 , see http://books.google.com/books?id=4slwHoIk-9AC&pg=PA21&dq=%22security+compromise%22&hl=en&ei=Z18ATuiVDYiCOofY5IYO&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22security%20compromise%22&f=false especially

Comment: @Unreason - "Security compromise" is not bad - but specifically, "a compromise of one's integrity" would *not* be understood to mean a security breach.  It's the "**one's**" that changes the meaning to personal.  In @Thilo's link, the full phrase is "account compromise".

Comment: Okay, dictionary.com has it. But you have to press "expand" to get there. And the dictionary on OS X does not have this meaning. How about other sources? I guess it has been recently added (as a response to it being used in that way).

Comment: @MT_Head, specifically "a compromise of one's integrity" is *usage example*, quoted verbatim. It is *not* a justification for usage here. Nor is it defining example. Replace it (while reading) with "compromise of security" - http://www.google.com/search?q=%22compromise%20of%20security%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en

Comment: @MT_Head: I think "security compromise" is even worse. That does sound like some (acceptable) middle ground was reached, trading off security versus other concerns. I.e. indicating a good thing. In the other examples, there is at least some more context to guide the reader towards the meaning (indicating a bad thing).

Comment: @Thilo, :) pressing expand matters not, other dictionaries carry similar meanings too, http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/compromise :A concession to something detrimental or pejorative: *a compromise of morality.*"; also the search result from books speak for themselves.

Comment: The dictionary.com definition fits, no contest here. But "a concession to something detrimental" is really not what it means in the security context. There needs to be "exposure to danger", an active attacker, or something like this. Certainly not a "concession", which implies a more or less willing agreement by the one affected. The "concession" is more like a pejorative version of the settlement reached by mutual agreement. So I would count the yahoo.com link as an example of a dictionary that does not allow the security context use.

Comment: @Unreason - I understood that it was a usage example, but when you quoted it in your answer I assumed it formed part of your answer, i.e. that you quoted it because you thought it would be helpful; I disagreed.  I agree that "compromise of security" would work much better as part of your answer than an inappropriate usage example; in fact I would suggest it.  However, I still think that "breach of security" is a better answer overall.

Comment: @MT_Head: "breach of security" is the better choice of words. But that does not make it a better answer to my question.

Comment: @Thilo, you are right; I was looking a bit more and found http://machaut.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/WEBSTER.sh?WORD=compromise, which has "3. A committal to something derogatory or objectionable; a prejudicial concession; *a surrender*; as, a compromise of character or right.", this dictionary is from 1913, 1828 version does not have this meaning; also I find http://www.1911encyclopedia.org/Compromise interesting

Comment: I think people are over-egging the omelette here. It's fairly clear that "compromise" is a wishy-washy word that mostly suggests other meanings than the one intended, and as @MT_Head has said, there are other, more commonly used, less ambiguous words. I don't quite see the point of trying to shoehorn "compromise" in here when e.g. "breach" will do just fine.

Comment: @Neil, you are right except for a fact that OP is asking: 'is it okay to also use the noun "compromise" in this context?'; I presume he is not looking for alternatives since he is aware, but want to collect arguments that would either justify or condemn usage. In another words - he might have a bet going on or something of sorts.